# CSS screen resolution adaption with browser's "zoom", "moz-zoom", etc

Tags: html, css, web, zooming, viewport

While searching for an easy way to make my menu (http://www.ck-game.com/newIndex.html) fit screen size I stumbled over the possibility of using the browser's zoom functionalities (zoom, moz-zoom, etc.). I could imagine that it's much easier than using "em", "%" and media queries to make an elastic layout, more so because I have background-images which need to keep aspect ratio. Is there anything that speaks against using it besides someone wanting to actually zoom in/out and then the menu would adjust to it?

EDIT:
Proof of concept: http://www.ck-game.com/newIndex.html
Please try with different viewports and see how well it adapts :) Tested in IE9, latest FF and latest Chrome. Works on Android devices, breaks on most iOS devices.

Comment: not helping you here but, love the background. so cool.

Comment: Thank you, very kind :) Added a proof of concept as edit, btw, check it out - it works perfectly fine for me!

Comment: it looks really good. can i ask how you did the background? the game looks good too. i might check it sometime if i get time from school.

Comment: I used a html5 canvas in the background. Everything's done with spritesheets and fading/moving. It's a hobby game and I'm a hobby developer - don't expect too much ^^

Comment: Fixed the remaining bugs. It works perfectly fine for me now. Tested also on my Android mobile phone (Samsung Galaxy SII). If you have other devices please tell me whether it worked or not. Thanks!

Comment: on iphone5 there is a white box at the background for some reason. https://www.dropbox.com/s/nee0lnt6xi8mqnp/Photo%20May%2004%2C%206%2030%2052%20AM.png

Comment: Oh hey thanks for the screenshot! I've got one from a first generation tablet too, same issue (though it looks even worse there). Android devices seem to work well. Did it look good in landscape mode with your iPhone5 as well?

Comment: nope similar with landscape. https://www.dropbox.com/s/buzg0jpj55b4xl8/Photo%20May%2004%2C%207%2001%2005%20AM.png

Comment: it looks like its a problem with safari. it looks like the landspace screenshot on above comment on my mac.